# less doesn't work

Tags: command-line, unix

Recently I've noticed that less command doesn't work.

```
$ ls | less                                                        
CertificateEntreprenuership101.pdf
Engineering Software as a Service_ An Agile Approach Using Cloud Computing_B00CCEHNUM copy.azw3
Photos.zip
Raspberry_Pi_Education_Manual.pdf
chef-v100
chef-v100.zip
node-webkit
postgresql-v400 2
postgresql-v400.zip
rd1_ua
rd1_ua.zip
```

As you can see it didn't open less as viewer. It might be some global setting but I have no idea what might it cause.

Update.

```
$ which less
/usr/bin/less
$ echo $LESS                                                           
-F -g -i -M -R -S -w -X -z-4
less <somefile> - works as expected
```

Comment: Is `LESS` set in the shell? What does `echo $LESS` return? Does `less some-text-file` work as expected?

Comment: Why are some parts of the output in blue?!

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco That’s the *Always* Perfect™ default syntax highlighter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From `man less`:

```
   -F or --quit-if-one-screen
          Causes  less  to  automatically  exit  if  the entire file can be displayed on the first
          screen.
```

Remove the option from `LESS` to avoid this.

Comment: Please point me to the documentation of 'echo $LESS', i've never heard of this expression.

Comment: `echo` is a shell command which prints all its arguments (try `echo Hello World`). `LESS` is a variable defined in your shell which can be addressed as `$LESS`. Combining this together you can use `echo $LESS` to display the content of this variable.

Comment: Why is the word “Causes” in blue? Strange.

Comment: @Nicolas Because it's the start of the line and the first letter is capital. The ‘default’ syntax highlighting style colours such text as blue.